avoid brute force typing of variable names
I am trying to automate a line of code that calls variables. It is in my "summarise" line of code below. Here is the code to create data and produce the summarise manually:
library(tidyverse)


# I have three data frames that I want to use later
mro <- c('19100', '19740')
aff <- c('50','80')
yrs <- c(21,22)

# create example data for this post
yr_pma <- rep(seq(from=2019, to=2021), 5)

set.seed(123)

p50_y22_19100 <- sample(0:12, 15, replace=TRUE) 
p80_y22_19100 <- sample(0:12, 15, replace=TRUE) 
p50_y21_19100 <- sample(0:12, 15, replace=TRUE) 
p80_y21_19100 <- sample(0:12, 15, replace=TRUE) 


p50_y21_19740 <- sample(0:12, 15, replace=TRUE) 
p80_y21_19740 <- sample(0:12, 15, replace=TRUE) 
p50_y22_19740 <- sample(0:12, 15, replace=TRUE) 
p80_y22_19740 <- sample(0:12, 15, replace=TRUE) 



comb_met <- data.frame(yr_pma, p50_y21_19100, p80_y21_19100, p50_y21_19740, p80_y21_19740, 
                               p50_y22_19100, p80_y22_19100, p50_y22_19740, p80_y22_19740)
comb_met

# manually create result
aff_result <- comb_met %>%
  group_by(yr_pma) %>%
  summarise(across(c(p50_y21_19100, p80_y21_19100, p50_y21_19740, p80_y21_19740,
                     p50_y22_19100, p80_y22_19100, p50_y22_19740, p80_y22_19740), sum, na.rm=TRUE))

aff_result

# ?? How can I create the "summarise()" line of code in an automated way from "mro", "aff", and "yrs"



With the data I create in the code above, I produce this result
> aff_result
# A tibble: 3 × 9
  yr_pma p50_y21_19100 p80_y21_19100 p50_y21_19740
   <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>
1   2019            33            29            35
2   2020            40            36            25
3   2021            41            37            19
# ℹ 5 more variables: p80_y21_19740 <int>,
#   p50_y22_19100 <int>, p80_y22_19100 <int>,
#   p50_y22_19740 <int>, p80_y22_19740 <int>
> 

The solution I'm shooting for would produce the same result (with dummy data I created in the post) and automate the creation of the line of code, so I can avoid the brute force method of typing the 50/80, 21/22, and '19100' / '19740' (and my actual data has many more allowable values) I'd like to pull them from the variables mro, aff, and yrs, that I defined in the post as this:
I've considered "matches" but haven't solved it. I'm not creating any new variables, just looking to summarise existing ones.
I want to replace this line, which is lengthy, and there are many more versions of these variables in the actual data.
summarise(across(c(p50_y21_19100, p80_y21_19100, p50_y21_19740, p80_y21_19740,
                     p50_y22_19100, p80_y22_19100, p50_y22_19740, p80_y22_19740), sum, na.rm=TRUE))

by pulling pieces of the variable names in in the summarise statement from these three other variables.
mro <- c('19100', '19740')
aff <- c('50','80')
yrs <- c(21,22)

I'm not sure what the solution is. I considered match()
The solution is posted in the text above. No new variables created, or calculations done. Just replicating how I write the summarise line.

comb_met |> summarise(across(where(is.integer), sum), .by = yr_pma)

Either pivot your data frame so that it is tidy (it isn't at the moment because the column names contain information that you need to perform your calculation)  before attempting to summarise or persist with matches (and its siblings starts_with etc.

Expanding on my suggestion to tidy your data in order to make life easier...
tidy_comb <- comb_met %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -yr_pma,
    names_to = c("Item1", "Item2", "Item3"),
    names_sep = "_",
    values_to = "Value"
  )
tidy_comb
# A tibble: 120 × 5
   yr_pma Item1 Item2 Item3 Value
    <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
 1   2019 p50   y21   19100     6
 2   2019 p80   y21   19100    10
 3   2019 p50   y21   19740     4
 4   2019 p80   y21   19740     1
 5   2019 p50   y22   19100     2
 6   2019 p80   y22   19100     8
 7   2019 p50   y22   19740     8
 8   2019 p80   y22   19740    11
 9   2020 p50   y21   19100     4
10   2020 p80   y21   19100     5
# ℹ 110 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

This makes your summary independent of column name.
ans <- tidy_comb %>% 
  group_by(yr_pma, Item1, Item2, Item3) %>% 
  summarise(
    Value = sum(Value, na.rm = TRUE),
    .groups = "drop"
  )
ans
# A tibble: 24 × 5
   yr_pma Item1 Item2 Item3 Value
    <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
 1   2019 p50   y21   19100    33
 2   2019 p50   y21   19740    35
 3   2019 p50   y22   19100    19
 4   2019 p50   y22   19740    32
 5   2019 p80   y21   19100    29
 6   2019 p80   y21   19740    23
 7   2019 p80   y22   19100    35
 8   2019 p80   y22   19740    23
 9   2020 p50   y21   19100    40
10   2020 p50   y21   19740    25
# ℹ 14 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

Numerically, these results match your expected output, though in long rather than wide format.
If you need the answer in wide format, pivot once more:
ans %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = c(Item1, Item2, Item3),
    names_sep = "_",
    values_from = Value
  )
# A tibble: 3 × 9
  yr_pma p50_y21_19100 p50_y21_19740 p50_y22_19100 p50_y22_19740 p80_y21_19100 p80_y21_19740 p80_y22_19100 p80_y22_19740
   <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>
1   2019            33            35            19            32            29            23            35            23
2   2020            40            25            21            21            36            26            40            25
3   2021            41            19            44            33            37            36            28            31


If these are your pre-defined vectors,
aff <- c('50','80')
yrs <- c(21,22)
mro <- c('19100', '19740')

then you can match these to the names in your data frame by using the following code for your matches argument:
apply(X=do.call(what=expand.grid, 
                args=list(paste0("p",aff), paste0("y",yrs), mro)), 
      MARGIN=1, FUN=paste, collapse="_")

which produces
"p50_y21_19100" "p80_y21_19100" "p50_y22_19100" "p80_y22_19100" "p50_y21_19740" "p80_y21_19740" "p50_y22_19740" "p80_y22_19740"

You can then use across as suggested by @LTyrone to summarise only those columns that match those that are defined previously:
comb_met %>%
  summarise(across(matches(apply(
    do.call(expand.grid, list(paste0("p",aff), paste0("y",yrs), mro)), 
    1, paste, collapse="_")), sum, na.rm=TRUE), .by=yr_pma)


yr_pma p50_y21_19100 p80_y21_19100 p50_y22_19100 p80_y22_19100 p50_y21_19740 p80_y21_19740 p50_y22_19740 p80_y22_19740
1   2019            33            29            19            35            35            23            32            23
2   2020            40            36            21            40            25            26            21            25
3   2021            41            37            44            28            19            36            33            31


Here's a simple way:
desired_cols <- paste0(c(mro, aff, yrs), collapse = "|")

aff_result <- comb_met %>%
  group_by(yr_pma) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(matches(desired_cols)), sum, na.rm = TRUE)


summarise_at has been superseded, as have all dplyr scoped verbs.
